# How to select rows which can have a given value in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an inventory management system. I have provided 5 fields for user to enter product category. Now I am rather confused How do I select rows which can have same product category in any of the five columns.

The schema is similar to

```
 id, name, size, cat1, cat2,cat3,cat4,cat5
```

What I want for example is that I want to select all items that have product category "Clothes", it should into all five columns and return me all distinct rows.  How can I do that?

Thank you so much.

Comment: It was a bad choice to design your table that way. In databases you should think in terms of 0, 1 or many, but not 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database should have been designed differently, where you would have the categories associated to a product stored in a separate table.

In the current model, you could make your query like this:

```
SELECT id, name, size
FROM   product
WHERE  "Clothes" IN (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5)
```

If you have another category to check for, like "Footwear", then it depends whether you are looking for products that have both categories or one of both:

1. Products that have **both** "Clothes" and "Footwear" categories (`AND`):

   ```
   WHERE  "Clothes" IN (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5)
   AND    "Footwear" IN (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5)
   ```
2. Products that have **at least one** of both categories (`OR`):

   ```
   WHERE  "Clothes" IN (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5)
   OR     "Footwear" IN (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5)
   ```

### Creating a view

You could consider creating a view to make it easier to make such, and more complex, queries:

```
CREATE VIEW product_cat (product_id, cat) AS
    SELECT id, cat1 FROM product UNION
    SELECT id, cat2 FROM product UNION
    SELECT id, cat3 FROM product UNION
    SELECT id, cat4 FROM product UNION
    SELECT id, cat5 FROM product;
```

And then you can do queries like:

```
SELECT     product.id, product.name, product.size, product_cat.cat
FROM       product
INNER JOIN product_cat ON product.id = product_cat.product_id
WHERE      product.cat LIKE 'C%';
```

This would list products with their categories, but only those categories that start with a *"C"*.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked!.   Actually we only require 5 fields per item. Thats why I am using it.  All fields are indexed though.

Comment: How to modify this query if I have more category phrases to search like Clothes, Footwear etc?